# How to use snowflake views and tables with Snaplogic

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snaplogic

I`m working as an BA in a project.
Now I have the task, to connect the existing views from SAP tables in Snowflake and connect all of these with snaplogic.
My question:
Is there in Snowflake something to prepare before using with snaplogic or is there some existing tools or something else.

I´m quite new, and would be happy if someone can assist here.

Thank you - Panda

Opportunity to have a solution for the connecting and preparing into snowflake

Comment: Hi - can you update your question with a clarification of what you are trying to achieve? Reading between the lines, I suspect s what you are trying to ask about is how to load data from SAP into Snowflake using Snaplogic - is this correct? If it is, then you need to ask a specific question about an issue you are having - for example, what have you tried and what are you stuck on?

Comment: Thank you for your response. At first, I`ve already the tables an attributes from the relevant and different tables as views in Snowflake. Now we are trying to send all this datas from snowflake to snaplogic or grant access to this datas from snaplogic to send this finally to a subsystem. At the end I need the data what I already have in snwoflake via Snaplogic to a subsystem. Hope it´`s bit clearer

Comment: OK - that's clearer regarding what you are asking. In case you're not aware, asking for tool/software recommendations is off-topic for this forum and is almost guaranteed to get your question closed. Also, on this forum you need to demonstrate that you have made at least some effort to answer the question yourself - so asking a generic question such as "how to move date from Snowflake to another system using Snaplogic?" is also likely to get your question closed. You need to show that you have done at least some research and then ask a specific question about an issue you are facing